# Accessing output variables in matrix job

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019

I am generating output variables in matrix job A:

```yaml
  - job: A
    strategy:
      matrix:
        nonprod:
          environment: test
        prod:
          environment: prod
    steps:
      - pwsh: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Hostname;isOutput=true]'StuffFrom$(environment)'"
        name: OutputVariable
```

Now I need to access them in subsequent matrix strategy in respective jobs:

```yaml
  - job: B
    dependsOn: A
    strategy:
      matrix:
        nonprod:
          environment: test
        prod:
          environment: prod
    steps:
      - pwsh: Write-Host How can I use output variables from job A in here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Shayki Abramczyk answer I ended up using this approach:

```yaml
  jobs:
  - job: A
    strategy:
     matrix:
      nonprod:
        environment: test
      prod:
        environment: prod
    steps:
      - pwsh: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Hostname;isOutput=true]'StuffFrom$(environment)'"
        name: OutputVariable
  - job: B
    dependsOn: A
    variables:
        varFromAprod: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['prod.OutputVariable.Hostname'] ]
        varFromAnonprod: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['nonprod.OutputVariable.Hostname'] ]
    strategy:
     matrix:
      nonprod:
        environment: test
        hostname: $(varFromAnonprod)
      prod:
        environment: prod
        hostname: $(varFromAprod)
    steps:
      - pwsh: |
          Write-Host Hostname for this job is $Hostname
```

Answer (score 4):

The `matrix` also accept a runtime expression containing a stringified JSON object. For example:

```yaml
    jobs:
    - job: generator
      steps:
      - bash: echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=legs;isOutput=true]{'a':{'myvar':'A'}, 'b':{'myvar':'B'}}"
        name: mtrx
      # This expands to the matrix
      #   a:
      #     myvar: A
      #   b:
      #     myvar: B
    - job: runner
      dependsOn: generator
      strategy:
        matrix: $[ dependencies.generator.outputs['mtrx.legs'] ]
      steps:
      - script: echo $(myvar) # echos A or B depending on which leg is running
```

Check here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?tab=yaml&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#multi-job-configuration

Comment: Looks promising, but how to expand this to actually run two parallel jobs in generator which produce those outputs rather than hardcoding them?

Comment: Can you elaborate it? How do you want to produce the outputs?

Comment: As an example I would create vms in job A one for test and one for prod in parallel, I would output their names and than use that in job B to perform some actions with each vm in parallel.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - I've set this up but in some situations the matrix is empty and then instead of not running the dependent job it fails on populating 'pool' from the empty matrix as we have `pool: $(imageName)` where imageName is normally set by the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You need to map the output variable, then you can use them. you can do it in this way:

```
  jobs:
  - job: A
    strategy:
     matrix:
      nonprod:
        environment: test
      prod:
        environment: prod
    steps:
      - pwsh: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Hostname;isOutput=true]'StuffFrom$(environment)'"
        name: OutputVariable
  - job: B
    dependsOn: A
    variables:
        varFromAprod: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['prod.OutputVariable.Hostname'] ]
        varFromAnonprod: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['nonprod.OutputVariable.Hostname'] ]
    strategy:
     matrix:
      nonprod:
        environment: test
      prod:
        environment: prod
    steps:
      - pwsh: Write-Host "$(varFromAprod)"
        name: PrintVariableProd
      - pwsh: Write-Host "$(varFromAnonprod)"
        name: PrintVariableNonprod
```

More info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts).

Comment: I probably should have emphasised more strongly that I need to use each variable in respective jobs, that is I need output of job A nonprod to be used specifically in nonprod of jon B, I can see how this could be done in the powershell task itself with some simple if statement provided your answer, but it feels like there should be a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: @AurimasN. I tried to make the variables available respective to the matrix but without success. if you will success please update here :)

Comment: I've edited my post below to a cleaner version than using if statement in the pwsh task.